# Django Rest Framework Postman 'POST' request error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm still having this error when trying to do a post request from postman.

```
{
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I can make the same post request successfully from my DRF localhost, but when i try on postman i get the error above.

How can I solve it?

**Views.py**

```
class PlayThingList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PlayThingSerializer
    queryset = PlayThing.objects.all()

class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password']

        extra_kwargs = {'password': {
            'write_only':True,
            'required':True
        }}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user)
        return user
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('playthings', PlayThingList, basename='playthings')
router.register('users', UserViewset)




urlpatterns = [
    path('playmates/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
app_name = 'playthings'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('playthings.urls')),
    path('auth/', obtain_auth_token)
]
```

**UPDATE**

I made some changes based on the error messages and guides in the comments and I can now create users.

Problem is, after sending the user credentials in the form, i get this error in postman.

[image]

Comment: As per the error, django is not recieving username and password fields. Can you make sure that you are sending those details from postman. Try by adding 'username' and 'password' in "Body" section of your request from postman.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried doing that. Both in the raw format and the x-www-form-urlencoded formats respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your POSTMAN

**Headers** section:

| KEY | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Accept | application/json |

**Body section** (choose raw or x-www-form-urlencoded):

| KEY | Value |
| --- | --- |
| username | (your username) |
| password | (your password) |

Comment: Thank you. I added the "Accept: application/json" to the headers section but i still get the same error.

Comment: I am getting this in my console after adding credentials to the body section.

[11/Mar/2022 06:09:24] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('username=jesus&password=christ')
[11/Mar/2022 06:09:24] "username=jesus&password=christ" 400 -

Comment: have you tried adding the credentials with x-www-form-urlencoded option of the body section bro as key value pairs?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Comment: what is your target post request url in postman?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/playmates/users/

Comment: ahh that you shouldve used localhost:8000/admin or your custom login view for user authentication mate. i hope you have already figured the problem out. as for your updated question : you should use GET request to retrieve the created users. 

model viewsets by default creates : create, retrieve ,destroy etc views for you. 
just head over to https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: Thank you very much!  I've solved the error!

Comment: Pleasure was all mine mate. Hope you have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

In your userviewset, you are using UserSerializer. This way you can not create users. To create a user you will have to extend registeruser functionality.

Check out the code from rest-framework and use the same logic in your create method of userviewset. if you want to register a user.

Registeruser is all together a different thing.

Rest framework by default has a url to register users, use that url, it will handle everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved!**

The issue was with the token create() method. I changed

```
create(user) to create(user=user)
```

**ref: serializers.py**

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

Thank you to everyone that helped!